# Writing CLPR output to console

Tags: prolog, clpr

I'm a very beginner to Prolog. I want to modify the code to write the output to the console. 
How can I write the output of this program to the console?

```
%
% from file: library('clpqr/examples/elimination')
%
conv(Points, Xs) :-
  lin_comb(Points, Lambdas, Zero, Xs),
  zero(Zero),
  polytope(Lambdas).

polytope(Xs) :-
  positive_sum(Xs, 1).

  positive_sum([], Z) :- {Z=0}.
  positive_sum([X|Xs], SumX) :-
    { X >= 0, SumX = X+Sum },
    positive_sum(Xs, Sum).

zero([]).
zero([Z|Zs]) :- {Z=0}, zero(Zs).

lin_comb([],        [],     S1, S1).
lin_comb([Ps|Rest], [K|Ks], S1, S3) :-
  lin_comb_r(Ps, K, S1, S2),
  lin_comb(Rest, Ks, S2, S3).

  lin_comb_r([],     _, [],     []).
  lin_comb_r([P|Ps], K, [S|Ss], [Kps|Ss1]) :-
    { Kps = K*P+S },
    lin_comb_r(Ps, K, Ss, Ss1).
```

Query :-

```
conv([ [1,1], [2,0], [3,0], [1,2], [2,2] ], [X,Y]).
```

Comment: The [tag:prolog-toplevel] already prints the output. Why do you want to do this yourself? With constraints like in your case CLPR  printing answers is often non-trivial as it includes the projection and display of equations.